# How to show loading bar in angular 4

Tags: angular, progress-bar

I am using angular 4. And trying to add loading bar, till I didn't get the response from the server side. When Request gets complete, it should not hide.
For this I am using below code In module.ts:

```
import { NgProgressModule } from 'ngx-progressbar';
@NgModule({
imports: [
    NgProgressModule
]
)}
```

And in Html file I am using below:

```
<ng-progress [positionUsing]="'marginLeft'"
[direction]="'leftToRightIncreased'"
[color]="'#4286f4'" [trickleSpeed]="500" 
[thick]="true" [ease]="'easeInSine'" ></ng-progress>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In components, wherever you need the progress bar, you have to

**`import { NgProgress } from 'ngx-progressbar';`**

and

```
constructor(private ngProgress: NgProgress) { 
}
```

use **`start()`** and **`stop()`** as you need

```
this.ngProgress.start();
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sajeetharan, for your intention toward this. It works for me, but instead of stop(), "done()" works for me. i.e: this.ngProgress.done();